# How can I detect if a network card is not connected with Java without delay?

Tags: java, api, network-programming

It there an API (NetworkInterface, InetAddress, etc) in Java with which I can detect that a network card is not connected.

The problem is that addressing some of the network API has a large timeout. But if the network card is not connected to any cable then we can skip it. The problem seems only to occur with Windows 7.

Comment: A lot of the timeout settings can be controlled at the JVM level (see Snicolas' response). Others, you have to set them up at the OS level, and you have to make them a OS-level `pre-condition` for your java app. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem, but it seems to me that at some point, your JVM deployment `must` make some assumptions about what is being provided by the underlying OS. Good question though (+1 for you).

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem.  I ended up using this:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> eni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while(eni.hasMoreElements()) {
            Enumeration<InetAddress> eia = eni.nextElement().getInetAddresses();
            while(eia.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress ia = eia.nextElement();
                if (!ia.isAnyLocalAddress() && !ia.isLoopbackAddress() && !ia.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    if (!ia.getHostName().equals(ia.getHostAddress()))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Works with Java 5+.  Also indirectly checks DNS (by comparing names/addresses).

Comment: The problem is that getHostName() blocks for around 5 seconds if the network cart is not connected.

Comment: It doesn't for me. If it's not connected the host name is the same as the host address. EDIT: then again, I'm checking an IPv6 stack, so I'm not sure about IPv4 behavior...I'd think it would be the same though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some java system properties to set up the default time out for socket connection using

```
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout
```

([all properties here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html))

But it seems to me that checking wether a specific Medium Access Controller is present or not is the job of the underlying OS. I can't tell you much about windows 7, I got a good OS since 12 years now (linux).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I sort of agree with you on this (that this is a OS-level task, not a JVM one.) OTH, one could make the case of trying to do this at the JVM level if one is implementing a container or framework (where the lines between app-level and systems-level expectations become blurred.)

Comment: I don't think changing the timeout will help. If you make it too short then it will timeout when there is an actual connection delay. But there are circumstances (such as not having a network card) when no network connection is possible, and the questioner wants to detect that immediately.